# Как в PIL расширить изображение, прибавив вниз белый блок?

Tags: python, pil, pillow

Использую PIL, а точнее актуальный форк Pillow. Как можно прибавить к используемому изображению вниз белый блок, тем самым расширив изображение?

```
fd = urllib.urlopen("http://img13.wikimart.ru/7e/7d/f76af011-5f3d-4f81-94b5-16633e7d7e0b.jpeg")
image_file = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
img = Image.open(image_file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у исходного изображения нет альфа-канала, то

```
white_block_height = 100

fd = urllib.urlopen("http://img13.wikimart.ru/7e/7d/f76af011-5f3d-4f81-94b5-16633e7d7e0b.jpeg")
image_file = io.BytesIO(fd.read())
img = Image.open(image_file)

background = Image.new('RGB', (img.size[0], img.size[1] + white_block_height), (255, 255, 255))
background.paste(img, (0, 0))
background.save('test.jpg')
```

Comment: О, большое спасибо, вы очень помогли!